# Six.iteritems(kwargs) и setattr, пояснить в коде?

Tags: python, django

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):

    for key, value in six.iteritems(kwargs):
        setattr(self, key, value)
```

Кто может пояснить действие этого куска кода в классе, а в особенности six.iteritems(kwargs) и 
setattr(self, key, value)?

Comment: Во многих случаях можно просто написать: `self.__dict__.update(kwargs)` вместо всего цикла. Или использовать готовый класс: `argparse.Namespace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Six - модуль для совместимости между Python 2 и 3.

```
six.iteritems(dictionary, **kwargs)
```

> Returns an iterator over dictionary‘s items. This replaces dictionary.iteritems() on Python 2 and dictionary.items() on Python 3. kwargs are passed through to the underlying method.

Т.е. из **dictionary.iteritems()** переводит в **dictionary.items()** или на оборот и возвращает итератор.

**setattr** -  переопределяет значение.

```
SetAttr (х, 'Foobar', 123) 
#эквивалентно 
x.foobar = 123.
```

Сделано это для совместимости между Python 2 и Python 3, чтобы не зависеть от версии.

Доки:

[SetAttr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr)

[Six](https://pythonhosted.org/six/)

Comment: `six.iteritems(d)` эквивалентен: `d.iteritems()` в Питоне 2, и `d.items()` в Питоне 3. Питон чуствителен к регистру букв, поэтому `SetAttr()` это ошибка (скорее всего) -- не такой встроенной функции. `setattr(x, 'Foobar', 123)` и `setattr(x, 'foobar', 123)` c *разными* атрибутами работают `x.Foobar` и `x.foobar` соответственно.

Comment: Ага, описался, мой косяк. setattr кончено же. С foobar так же. Спасибо, что поправили)